# seekg and imbue in wifstream work wrong

Tags: c++, c++11, locale, wifstream

I have a file like below:

```
$ xxd 1line
0000000: 3939 ba2f 6f20 6f66 0d0a                 99./o of..
```

I would like to read this one line in C++:

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::wifstream wss(argv[1], std::ios::binary);
  wss.seekg(std::ios_base::end);
  const auto fileSize = wss.tellg();
  wss.seekg(std::ios_base::beg);

  // std::locale utf8_locale(wss.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t, 0x10FFFF, std::consume_header>);
  // wss.imbue(utf8_locale);

  std::wstring wline;
  std::getline(wss, wline);

  std::cout << "filelen: " << fileSize << std::endl;
  std::cout << "strlen: " << wline.size() << std::endl;
  std::wcout << "str: " << wline << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I compile it in below way:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 imbue_issue.cpp
```

First thing: it seems that wss.seekg(std::ios_base::end) does not moves file position at the end of the file:

```
$ ./a.out 1line
filelen: 2
strlen: 9
str: 99?/o of
```

Second thing is when uncomment locale related lines, getline reads only 2 characters:

```
$ ./a.out 1line
filelen: 2
strlen: 2
str: 99
```

My compiler:

```
$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Does anyone have idea what is the reason why above issues occur with this file?

Comment: What is the size of `wchar_t` on your system? I'll bet that it's `4`. That means the size of the file is 2.5 `wchar_t` characters large, which gets truncated to `2`.

Comment: Yes, it is 4 bytes.

Comment: Also, judging by the data-dump of the file contents, it doesn't seem to be a file of wide characters, but of narrow characters. Try using "ordinary" narrow `char` instead, and see what results you get.

Comment: Funny thing, when I changed from wifstream to ifstream, the fileSize still equals 2. Is ifstream based on char? I checked that sizeof(char) on my system is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you call [the `seekg` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg). When you call it with one argument it is used as an absolute position *from the beginning*, and you will seek to whatever value `std::ios::end` have, which happens to be `2` in your case.

Instead you should use the two-argument overload:

```
wss.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);  // Seek to offset 0 from the end
```

You will still have problems reading the file using wide-character types, since the contents doesn't seem to be that. UTF-8 is a multi-byte *narrow* character encoding.

Comment: I understand that imbue problem is related with using wifstream instead of ifstream, right?
Is there any generic way of reading files in C++ if we don't know what contents are? If not, how to programmatically decide if ifstream of wifstream is needed?

Comment: @mkk No there's really no good way of detecting how the data was saved or its encoding, unless the file has some kind of header or similar like the UTF-8 [byte-order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Answer (score 0):

I found that someone had similar issues with getline:

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15733